# Storing Conversation Messages for Android Auto in strings.xml

Tags: android, string, resources, android-auto

I have seen that in the following android auto sample - https://developer.android.com/samples/MessagingService/index.html

message conversations are stored in an array in Conversation.java class. I know that in real world it should be done using a content provider. But, currently, i want to make it simple.

Is it possible that i can store such messages in strings.xml file in android project? (I mean in the resource folder), reason being I want to trigger such messages based on some condition I have received on my broadcast receiver.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: SharedPreference is good in this case i think.

Comment: Oh..I see..But how can I store around 4-5 messages?

Comment: use Keys for sharedPreference According to your messages.

Comment: I feel shared pref is good option. But, can I use it in a simple Java class instead of Activity? I do not want to store it in an activity. If i do it in a class, it needs a context and it would ask me can not resolve getSharedPreferences.

Comment: Application class is an option but it will retain only for SomeTime(till app is in RecentTask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing it in strings.xml itself is fine. 
Another option is to have a static array of those strings.

strings.xml will be more flexible when it comes to localization